# What is the categorical-theoretical generalization of order-embeddings and downsets?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, order-theory

**NB:** even though this question's longish setup gives the impression that it is about the theory of ordered sets, in fact it is really more general than that.  The setup here serves only as the immediate motivation for a much more general question (about category theory) at the end.

---

In what follows, $(P, \leq)$ and $(Q, \leq)$ are always posets.

If $\varphi: (P, \leq) \to (Q, \leq)$, we say that $\varphi$ is **monotone** iff $(x \leq y) \Rightarrow (\varphi(x) \leq \varphi(y))$.  We say that $\varphi$ is an **order-embedding** iff $\forall x, y \in P: (x \leq y) \Leftrightarrow (\varphi(x) \leq \varphi(y))$.

For any poset $(P,\leq)$, we say that $Y \subseteq P$ is a **downset** of $(P, \leq)$ iff $((y \in Y)\;\wedge\; (x \leq y)) \Rightarrow (x \in Y)$.

We denote by ${\mathcal O}(P) \subseteq \wp(P)$ the set of all the downsets of $(P, \leq)$.

**Claim 1**: $\varphi: (P, \leq) \to (Q, \leq)$ is monotone iff $\forall A \in {\mathcal O}(Q): \varphi^{-1}(A) \in {\mathcal O}(P).$

If $\varphi: (P, \leq) \to (Q, \leq)$ is monotone, Claim 1 implies that $\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}(A) = \varphi^{-1}(A)$ specifies a well-defined map $\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}: {\mathcal O}(Q) \to {\mathcal O}(P)$.

For the next two claims, assume that the map $\varphi: (P, \leq) \to (Q, \leq)$ is monotone.

**Claim 2**: $\varphi: (P, \leq) \to (Q, \leq)$ is an order-embedding iff the corresponding map $\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}: {\mathcal O}(Q) \to {\mathcal O}(P), A \mapsto \varphi^{-1}(A)$ is a surjection.

**Claim 3**: $\varphi: (P, \leq) \to (Q, \leq)$ is a surjection iff the corresponding map $\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}: {\mathcal O}(Q) \to {\mathcal O}(P), A \mapsto \varphi^{-1}(A)$ is an injection.

---

OK, so much for setup.

I don't know much category theory, but I know *just enough* of it to recognize that the first two lines in the setup above are describing the **Poset** category, whose objects are posets and whose morphisms are the monotone maps.

**Question:** what, if any, would be the "category-theoretical rendition" of the remainder of this setup?

More specifically, what are the general categorical concepts/terms/theorems for the roles played in this setup by the following?

- the order-embeddings;
- a downset of a poset;
- the set ${\mathcal O}(P)$ of all downsets of a poset $(P, \leq)$;
- the map $\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}: {\mathcal O}(Q) \to {\mathcal O}(P)$ induced by the morphism $\varphi: (P, \leq) \to (Q, \leq)$;
- Claim 1;
- Claim 2;
- Claim 3.

Comment: The generalisation of this from posets to categories is basically the Yoneda embedding. But are you asking about the generalisation of this from the category of posets to general categories of arbitrary objects…?

Comment: @ZhenLin: thank you for your comment.  I'm just wondering how the above write-up would have been written for an "arbitrary category", or, in case that is too general, then for an "arbitrary X category" (X="small"?  X="concrete"?), where X is as general as possible.  (Unfortunately, if I knew enough category theory to ask the question coherently, I probably would also know the answer to it!)